# I can't get the Mask Artifact "Traveling Tiki"

Tags: temple-run-2

I am level 10 I completed all the activities. I found all the artifacts except Traveling Tiki .

I run 103065 meters in one run. But I never got it.

Comment: What game is this? The question doesn't fit any of the three games you tagged this question with

Answer (score 1):

Traveling Tiki is one of the mask artifacts and does turn up from time to time. Starting with the Dec 2014 update, some effort was made to make the artifacts that you don't already have more likely to appear.

Note that you can only get one artifact per run, so once you've grabbed a chest you may as well die, see what it is, and start again if the main thing you are interested in is the artifacts.  Continuing a long run after you've already grabbed an artifact won't get you any more.